# Finding smallest numbers Python numpy list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a Python 3 list which contains arbitrary number of numpy arrays of varying size/shape. The problem is to remove the smallest p% (where, p = 20%, say) of number (in terms of magnitude) in the list to zero.

Example code:

```
l = []

l.append(np.random.normal(1.5, 1, size = (4, 3)))
l.append(np.random.normal(1, 1, size = (4, 4)))
l.append(np.random.normal(1.8, 2, size = (2, 4)))


for x in l:
    print(x.shape)

'''                                            
(4, 3)
(4, 4)
(2, 4)
'''
```

How can I remove smallest p% of numbers from 'l' Python list "globally", this means that for all of the numpy arrays contained within the list 'l', it will remove the smallest p% of the smallest numbers (in terms of magnitude) to zero?

I am using Python 3.8 and numpy 1.18.

Thanks!

Toy example:

```
l
'''
[array([[ 0.95400011,  1.95433152,  0.40316605],
        [ 1.34477354,  3.24612127,  1.54138912],
        [ 1.158594  ,  0.77954464,  0.4600395 ],
        [-0.03092974,  3.55349303,  0.85526191]]),
 array([[ 2.33613547,  0.12361808,  0.27620035,  0.70452795],
        [ 0.76989846, -0.28613191,  1.90050011,  2.73843595],
        [ 0.13510186,  0.91035556,  1.42402321,  0.60582303],
        [-0.13655066,  2.4881577 ,  2.0882935 ,  1.40347429]]),
 array([[-1.63365952,  1.2616223 ,  0.86784273, -0.34538727],
        [ 1.37161267,  2.4570491 , -0.72419948,  1.91873343]])]
'''
```

'l' has 36 numbers in it. Now 20% of 36 = 7.2 or rounded down = 7. So the idea is that 7 smallest magnitude numbers out of 36 numbers are removed by masking them to zero!

Comment: You want to remove the bottom 20% of each element of the list ?

Comment: Remove as in pop those elements from the array (not possible since arrays need a fixed shape) or replacing them with zero?

Comment: @JohnyVaknin remove as in mask the removed numbers/values to zero

Comment: @Guillaume No, I want to remove the bottom 20% of all np arrays contained in the list variable 'l' by masking them to zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
p = 20 #percentile to remove
lower = np.percentile(np.hstack([x.flatten() for x in l]), p)
for x in l:
  x[x<lower] = 0
```

You basically stack all numbers into single array and using `np.percentile`, find the threshold for p% lower bound and then filter arrays using the lower threshold.

Comment: Please checkout the posted solution. If that is not what you are looking for, please clarify what you intend to do after removing bottom p% and a non-rectangular array (which does not exist in numpy). Maybe a toy example of input and desired output will help us better understand the question. Thank you

Comment: @Arun Thanks for clarifying the question. I edited the answer to meet your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following. It looks for the threshold value and update the list in place to 0 when the value is under the threshold.

Let me know if you need more details

```
import numpy as np

l = []

l.append(np.random.normal(1.5, 1, size = (4, 3)))
l.append(np.random.normal(1, 1, size = (4, 4)))
l.append(np.random.normal(1.8, 2, size = (2, 4)))

acc = []
p = 20 #percentile to update to 0

for x in l:
    acc.append(x.flatten())

threshold = np.percentile(np.concatenate(acc),p)

for x in l:
  x[x < threshold] = 0
```